# Jackson Polymorphism - Abstract class with no property

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I have several Json strings as follows:

```
{"type1": {"name": "Arnold"}}
{"type2": {"id": "abcd", "job": "plumber"}}
```

The thing I want to end up with is converting a json string to one of the  classes `Type1` or `Type2` **depending on the root property of element**:

```
// Type0 abstract class
public abstract class Type0 {
}

// Type1 class.. convert to it if {"type1": {...}}
@JsonRootName(value = "type1")
public class Type1 extends Type0 {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
}

// Type2 class.. convert to it if {"type2": {...}} 
@JsonRootName(value = "type2")
public class Type2 extends Type0 {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("job")
    String job;
}
```

How to configure the `ObjectMapper` of Jackson so that I can achieve that deserialization? I think of a logic like the follows, is it doable:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
result = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Type0.class);
//TODO: code for deciding whether result is Type1 or Type2 and casting to it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson supports such a case with [WRAPPER_OBJECT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#WRAPPER_OBJECT). Annotate the abstract class like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "type1", value = Type1.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "type2", value = Type2.class)})
abstract class Type0 {}
```

and then when parsing `Type0.class` with `readValue` you will get an instance of the appropriate derived class. You don't need `@JsonRootName` over the derived classes.